# How to change column check constraint in table

Tags: sql, firebird

I have a column `Column1 integer check(column1 >=0) not null unique;`. Now i want to change the column so that the column1 has check value of <=0. I have already tried: `alter table table1 alter column column1 type integer check(column1 <=0) not null unique;` But it doesn't work. Any solutions?

Answer (score 2):

So as you said what is your database this is the command you need:

```
alter table table1 add constraint CK_NEGATIVEVALUES check ( column1 <=0 )
```

You don't alter a column to add a check you alter a table to add a `CONSTRAINT CHECK`